# How do I filter data based on multiple Graphic geometries in ArcGis Feature layer?

Tags: angular, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Here is my code.

```
let query = layer.createQuery();
query.geometry = geometry_here;
query.outFields = ["*"];
query.returnGeometry = true;

layer.queryFeatures(query).then((result) => {
    console.log('result of principle transmission layer', result);
    // i get filtered result here but i want to apply direct on layer
});
```

I'm only getting filter data with this way but I want to apply filter on layer.

Comment: which version of the API is this for? It looks like version 4.* but I want to be sure.

Comment: @Ryan we are using 4.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [FeatureLayerView.filter](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-FeatureLayerView.html#filter) which will require some additional wiring when adding the FeatureLayer to the map I'm assuming youa re using a MapView though similar functionality exists for scenes. You have a large number of options in defining the spatial relationship of the filter. See the documentation on the [spatialRelationship](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-support-FeatureFilter.html#spatialRelationship) property of a FeatureFilter

```
const view = new MapView({
   container: "sceneDiv",
   map: map,
   center: [-73.95, 40.702],
   zoom: 13,
   padding: {
     right: 300
   }
});
var layer = new FeatureLayer(url);

map.add(layer);

view.whenLayerView(layer)
    .then(function(layerView) {
      // The layerview for the layer is available here
      featureLayerView.filter = new FeatureFilter({

          geometry: geometry_here,
          spatialRelationship: "contains"
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // An error occurred during the layerview creation
    });
```

Comment: can we pass multiple geometries here?

Comment: you'll have to read the documentation and see. If not then you will need to join the geometries using the GeometryEngine.union function. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-geometryEngine.html#union

Comment: Thanks buddy i'll check it.